# Sharepoint. Modify dynamic content at runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint

Is there any way to modify dynamic content of SharePoint pages (let's say company news, or some other text info) at runtime before the page shows up to user? I know at least two methods how to do this:

1. Override some page render method and modify pure HTML before sending it.
2. Register startup client script and modify content on client side.

But I'm interesting if there is any standard way to do this via some events or content handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done. The trick is to use custom IHttpHandler, then connect dll to sharepoint via web.config - it will be filtering (and changing if needed) all site contents, including dynamic AJAX request contents.